# Access to a variable in an iframe by jquery selector

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have following:

```
<iframe id="test">
   <script>
     variable='hi';
   </script>
</iframe>
```

I need to know how can I access to a variable by jquery selector from the top window like this $("#test").variable ?

Comment: what does the iframe contain? does it display some other domains content?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try :

```
$("#test")[0].contentWindow.variable;
```