# get javascript variable from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html content, which gets fetched from the database and pasted into an iframe. The html content is something like the below,

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body style="background:#ffffff;">
<script>var el_list_obj = {'1_akdvf':{name:"test.png", width:"250px", height:"200px"},'2_akdvf':{name:"test2.png", width:"350px", height:"300px"}};</script>
<img style="top: 0px; left: 1px; width: 250px; z-index: 1; height: 200px; opacity: 1; transform: rotate(0deg);" class="slide-elements" src="/media-files/test.png">
<img style="top: 0px; left: 1px; width: 350px; z-index: 1; height: 300px; opacity: 1; transform: rotate(0deg);" class="slide-elements" src="/media-files/test2.png">
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the el_list_obj variable from the script, how to fetch this using javascript or jquery ?

I tried the below,

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(); // Sandbox
doc.body.innerHTML = rData['body_content'];
var scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTagName('script');
var arrayScriptContents = [].map.call(scriptElements, function(el) {
 self.elWinDataObj = el.textContent;
});
```

But it returns me the below as a string,

```
var el_list_obj = {'1_akdvf':{name:"test.png", width:"250px", height:"200px"},'2_akdvf':{name:"test2.png", width:"350px", height:"300px"}};
```

I want the below as a javascript object,

```
{'1_akdvf':{name:"test.png", width:"250px", height:"200px"},'2_akdvf':{name:"test2.png", width:"350px", height:"300px"}};
```

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6649090/3008050

Comment: you can json.parse(el_list_obj)

Comment: @Geeky It's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar why? I see no problem with it

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin It has single quotes instead of double quotes around the strings.

Comment: And some of the object keys don't have quotes around them at all.

Answer (score 0):

try using eval();

```
var b=`var el_list_obj = {'1_akdvf':{name:"test.png", width:"250px", height:"200px"},'2_akdvf':{name:"test2.png", width:"350px", height:"300px"}};`;

eval(b);
```

and you can access object by its name:

```
console.log(el_list_obj["1_akdvf"]);
```

Comment: Never use `eval` for something you can do without it.

Comment: yes, I agree. but in this case, with small data it is not big problem. But I’m not saying you should start using eval() everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the JSON object without the variable name, you can try this. Note that you'll need to make some changes to you current JSON to store it as a string.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
 var str = 'var el_list_obj = {"1_akdvf":{name:"test.png", width:"250px", height:"200px"},"2_akdvf":{name:"test2.png", width:"350px", height:"300px"}};'
 var out = iDontUseEval(str);
 console.log(out);
});

function iDontUseEval(fn) {
 if(fn.startsWith("var")){
   var evaluateThis = fn.substr(fn.indexOf("=")+1).trim()
   return new Function('return ' + evaluateThis)();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```